# Why does my Geforce RTX3070 run beyond boost clock without overclocking?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, overclocking

I bought a brand new Gigabyte RTX3070 Gaming OC (Rev 1), which according to [its specs](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Graphics-Card/GV-N3070GAMING-OC-8GD-rev-10/sp#sp) has a boost core clock of 1815 MHz. A quick look into GPU-Z confirms that number, see the following screenshot:

[image]

What I'm a bit surprised about is that GPU-Z, and also the on-screen display in MSI Afterburner reports a constant clock of 1950MHz while the GPU is under load, see again a screenshot:
[image]

I haven't done any core clock adjustments, as you can see here, for example:

[image]

How can we explain this clock difference of 135MHz? I'm using plain NVidia drivers and no overclocking.

Comment: I believe the NVidia drivers boost even higher than max boost if it sees that the system is thermally capable of handling it. Meaning if the system and GPU are not too hot, it will push the clock rate even further.

Answer (score 1):

So the manufactures aren't very clear about this but the number they put on their boost clocks specs is the **minimum** boost clock you can expect from the card. It uses a dynamic boost and will go as high as it can go safely. This applies to NVIDA and AMD.

I've seen quite a few YouTube videos testing cards and they all went at least 100 MHz higher than the boost clock on the spec sheet with no changes to any configurations. Nothing is wrong with your card, it's functioning normally.